# Does Autodesk Forge support rendering \ viewing 3D PDF files

Tags: autodesk-forge

When converting PDFs with 3D content to the SVF format using the Forge API\SDK it only seems to generate 2D artifacts.   Does the Forge platform support viewing 3D PDF's in general?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this's not supported as of now - will have a word with Engineering to see if that's on the road map and come back to update this answer.

Alternatively you could try load the PDF using the built-in plugin [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/fast-pdf-viewingmarkup-inside-forge-viewer) and see the 3D contents are rendered (most likely not supported either though)